# How can I use the spread operator with 'this'?

Tags: node.js, typescript, spread-syntax

I am defining a class in TypeScript.
So with the spread operator I can issue something like this:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(data: IDataStructure){
      const { ...k } = data; // and then k has taken over all the properties of data. Great!
  }

  public render () {

    return(<div/>

   );
  }
}
```

Now, I would love to do the same but not to put the properties in `k` but in the current object that is being created. I.e. I would like to do something like `const { ...this } = data;` Is there any smart way to do this in Typescript?

Comment: `...` isn't (and cannot be) an operator. It's just primary syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use spread to add properties to an *existing* object. There's no current *syntax* way of doing it; instead, use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
Object.assign(this, data);
```

Example *(in JavaScript)*:

```js
class Example {
    constructor(data) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}
const e = new Example({answer: 42});
console.log(e.answer); // 42
```

Note that `Object.assign` does a *shallow copy* of the properties. So if one of `data`'s properties refers to an object, that *reference* is copied over, and both `data` and `this` will refer to the same object:

```
const data = {
    answer: 67,
    obj: {
        prop: "value"
    }
};
Object.assign(this, data);
console.log(this.obj === data.obj); // true, it's a shallow copy, they both refer
                                    // to the same object
```

If you need a *deep* copy, where copying `data` also makes a copy of `data.obj`, see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).

Comment: I just found out it is not really working. What it does actually is to screw up your class. From that point on, whenever you wanna access the variables of the class thourough 'this' it is screwed as 'this' is now pointing to data.

Comment: @Jose - No, it isn't. `this` has a shallow copy of what's on `data`. I've added a note about deep cloning to the answer, but nothing in your question suggested that you wanted a deep copy.